# getActionBar returns null despite Usual Suspects

Tags: android

I have a background pinger to a REST service and want to change the action bar color when the connection has gone bad.

- I am extending AppCompatActivity
- I am using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
- I have tried adding  `<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>` to the theme explicitly
- I have tried .requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)

using the getSupportActionBar works but I'm on API level 22 and don't want to write new, deprecated code if it can be avoided. Pointers?

I debugged through the libraries and the getActionBar return return null when it notices a null parent reference at one point.

Comment: please include the code u have tried..

Comment: if you are using AppCompatActivity then you have to work with getSupportActionBar as that is for the support library. I assume you are using AppCompatActivity because you want to be backwards compatible. getSupportActionBar is a backwards compatible component for the action bar and is supposed to be used with AppCompatActivity